# What is the benefit of extending a generic by specifying the new type as actual type of generic

Tags: java, generics

I saw this pattern somewhere:

```
class A extends B<A> {

}
```

This structure is a little unusual to extend a generic by specifying the new type as actual type of generic. What is the use? Is there a name for this pattern? Is there any alternative pattern?

Example: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent

Jump to: `public class EditIssue extends LoadableComponent<EditIssue> {`

Edit:
After reading the responses, it seems that I need to alter my understanding of type checking by the compiler. At the back of my mind, my beef with this pattern was, if the two A's need to be same then is there a way to not repeat them? But it seems that there is no better way to propagate the derived class's type to the parent.

Comment: It might be interesting to give an example of where you've seen this in the wild.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: No need for tags in titles. There's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: `public class A extends B<A>{
    
}

class B<T> {

    Set<T> set = new HashSet();
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course the OOP answer is that `A` is a `B`. If `A` were not a `B` than `A` should merely compose itself with a `B` to make use of `B`'s functionality.

Presumably `B` also has some general implementations which take advantage of restrictions placed on the generic type.

Another use case would be for `B` to look something like:

```
abstract class B<T extends B<T>> {
    public T createCopy(T t);
}
```

Now subclasses can implement `createCopy` and client code can safely use it without having to cast... e.g.

```
class A extends B<A> {
    public A createCopy(A t) {
        return new A(t); //copy constructor
    }
}
```

Compare the above to:

```
abstract class B {
    public B createCopy(B t);
}
class A extends B {
    public B createCopy(B t) { //Is the copy an A or a different subtype of B? We don't know.
        return new A(t); //copy constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `B<T extends B<T>>`.

Answer (score 4):

You might do something like this when dealing with [recursive data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_data_structures_.28structural_recursion.29). For example, nodes in a graph or a tree could be defined as a collection of other nodes:

```
class Node extends AbstractList<Node> {
    ...
}
```

Equally you might see something like this if the abstract/generic type is meant for comparing objects of a similar type, such as is the case with `java.lang.Comparable`:

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
    public int compareTo(MyObject other) { ... }
}
```

Comment: @TimBender `class Node extends AbstractList<Node>`

Comment: When I first saw this, I swear it said `implements Collection<Node>`.

Answer (score 2):

Take this example:

```
E extends Comparable<E>
```

This means that E must be a type that knows how to compare to itself, hence, the recursive type definition.

Don't know if it has any official names, but I would call it *recursive generic type pattern*.

Comment: Typically you will have `class MyType implements Comparable<MyType>`. And as `java.lang.Enum` implements `Comparable`, you get the classic `class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`.

Comment: in your example, a type variable references itself. this is different from the question, where a class references itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed perplexing, since the two types `A` and `B<A>` appear to rely on each other to exist; that doesn't make much sense in ordinary OOP, so what is it for? I found 3 use cases for this pattern.

#### Composition turned Inheritance

Say a `Node` *has a* list of child Nodes. The usual design is through composition

```
class Node
    ArrayList<Node> children = ...
```

Sometimes for a small performance gain, people use inheritance instead

```
class Node extends ArrayList<Node>
    // the super class represents the children...
```

This is a little confusing, but there's nothing hard to understand. We know it's just a convenience, it does not try to convey that a node *is a* list of nodes.

`LoadableComponent` can be considered of this use case. It's arguably a less ideal design than a composition approach

```
class ComponentLoader<C>
    C get(){...}

class EditIssue
    final ComponentLoader<EditIssue> loader = new ComponentLoader<EditIssue>(){
        @Override void load(){...}
        @Override void isLoaded(){...}
    };

EditIssue compo = ...
compo.loader.get().doSomething();
```

The designer might find this approach more boiler platey.

#### Method Chaining

Instead of writing

```
foo.doA();
foo.doB();
```

a lot of people would rather want to write

```
foo.doA().doB();
```

Unfortunately the language doesn't directly support method chaining even though it is becoming an increasingly desired feature. The workaround is for `doA()` to return `foo`. It is a little dirty but acceptable.

However if `foo` is in a type hierarchy the workaround is broken

```
class Bar
    Bar doA()

class Foo extends Bar
    Foo doB();

foo.doA().doB(); // doesn't compile, since doA() returns Bar
```

So some people call for a special "self type" to solve this problem. Let's say there's a keyword `This` to represent "self type"

```
class Bar
    This doA()

foo.doA().doB(); // works, doA() returns the type of foo, which is Foo
```

It appears that method chaining is the only use case for "self type", so the language probably will never introduce it (it's better to just support method chaining directly)

People found out that generics provides a workaround for this problem

```
class Bar<This>
    This doA()

class Foo extends Bar<Foo>

Foo has a method "Foo doA()", inherited from Bar<Foo>
```

This is the most popular use case for the `A extends B<A>` pattern. It is an isolated  workaround/trick. It adds no semantics in relationship between A and B.

It is also a popular practice to constraint `This` like

```
class Bar<This extends Bar<This>>
```

It is ugly and useless, I strongly recommend against it. Simply use "This" as a convention to indicate what it is for.

`LoadableComponent` can also fall in this use case. In a simpler design we could do

```
class LoadableComponent
    void ensureLoaded()

class EditIssue extends LoadableComponent

EditIssue compo = ...
compo.ensureLoaded();
compo.doSomething();
```

To support method chaining of the last two lines, `LoadableComponent` is designed in its current form, so that we can write `compo.get().doSomething()`

#### Something more meta

So the previous two use cases are kind of hacks. What if there's a genuine constraint between `A` and `B<A>`?

Rather than serving as an ordinary super type, `B` is more meta, it describes that a type `A` should have some properties that reference `A` itself. This is not inheritance in traditional OOP's sense, it is something more abstract. (Though it is still implemented through traditional inheritance mechanism, it's imaginable that the language can promote it as a standalone concept.)

`Comparable` is of this use case. It describes that a certain type can compare to itself. Since it is not a traditional OOP type, ideally we should never declare an object with static type `Comparable`. We don't see it in public method return/parameter type, it won't make much sense. Instead we see things like

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> 
void sort(List<T>)
```

here the method requires a type that conforms to the Comparable pattern.

(I don't really know what I'm talking about in this section)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is the same as any other sub-class. What's really happening when a generic is used is the JVM is creating a copy (not actually a copy, but it's kinda-sorta like that) of a class, and replacing all the spots where the generic is used with the specified type.

So, to answer your question, all that pattern is doing is substituting `B<A>` for `B` in which all the uses of `A` are substituted with whatever class `A` is. Potential uses for this are in cases where you are customizing a data structure (from `java.util.Collections`) for a specific class, such as using bitshifts to compact a `Collection<Boolean>` into a smaller amount of memory. I hope that makes sense!