# Java generics: Use this type as return type?

Tags: java, generics, this, setter

I'm trying to make an API as user friendly as possible.

Let's have:

```
class B extends A {}

class A {
    A setX(){ ...; return this; }
}
```

Now this

```
B b = new B().setX();
```

is invalid, has to be casted:

```
B b = (B) new B().setX();
```

Is there a way using generics in `A` to make compiler aware of "this" type and accept the first way - without casting and without passing type parameter at the place where used? (I.e. not `new B<B>().setX()`, that's ugly.)

**I KNOW** why Java needs retyping in this case. Please no answers explaing that `setX()` returns A. ***I know that.***
I am asking if generics can solve this.

And for those still wanting to tell me that "this is how static typing works" and "not even generics can help with that", consider this valid Java code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap(){{ put( "foo", new RuntimeException() );
String foo = map.get("foo");  // ClassCastException!!
```

So you can see that generics DO allow you get a CCE without actual type cast appearing in the code.
That's the reason why I expect generics to allow getting rid of the explicit type cast.

Also, IIRC [C++ allows that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: The problem here is that a sub class can't hold an object reference declared of a super class, this necessarily needs a downcasting. Not even generics will help you here.

Comment: They could, potentially. It doesn't need downcasting per se.

Comment: Well, you could say `<T extends A> T setX() { return (T)this; }` but note that you're downcasting here.

Comment: Tried, still needs a cast...

Comment: You cannot guarantee to the compiler that the method will return a B object and so will need to cast. Get used to it.

Comment: Please stop adding *Java* and *Generics* to your title. The question is already tagged with both. Or do you think any non-java programmer would try to answer this question?

Comment: Using generics you supress such casts as well. This is just another use case of them. Should be allowed if it's not.

Comment: Generics do not suppress this.

Comment: I'm deleting the question and I'll repost when I get rid of someone renaming my questions.

Comment: Refer to meta: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/182862). It's not like me having something against you =\. Please come back after growing up.

Comment: Refer to real standards and look at right. Everyone includes "Java" and "generics" in related questions. Go agead and rename them.

Comment: @OndraŽižka that's because lot of people who does it are new to the site and doesn't read meta (just to note you: those are **the rules** in this site).

Comment: This particular rule is wrong, because if I look at the list of questions, I appreciate having a basic context in the header. Reading tags is unpleasant.

Comment: Found something related: [2. You can have method overloads differing only in return types](http://jaxenter.com/10-things-didnt-know-java-112603.html)

Comment: Typescript has the desired concept here (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) so this question is valid as written.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I copy part of the [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099185/what-is-the-benefit-of-extending-a-generic-by-specifying-the-new-type-as-actual/17100874#17100874) here, explaining the desire for the so called "self type" and the workaround in Java.

#### Method Chaining

Instead of writing

```
foo.doA();
foo.doB();
```

a lot of people would rather want to write

```
foo.doA().doB();
```

Unfortunately the language doesn't directly support method chaining even though it is becoming an increasingly desired feature. The workaround is for `doA()` to return `foo`. It is a little dirty but acceptable.

However if `foo` is in a type hierarchy the workaround is broken

```
class Bar
    Bar doA()

class Foo extends Bar
    Foo doB();

foo.doA().doB(); // doesn't compile, since doA() returns Bar
```

So some people call for a special "self type" to solve this problem. Let's say there's a keyword `This` to represent "self type"

```
class Bar
    This doA()

foo.doA().doB(); // works, doA() returns the type of foo, which is Foo
```

It appears that method chaining is the only use case for "self type", so the language probably will never introduce it (it's better to just support method chaining directly)

People found out that generics provides a workaround for this problem

```
class Bar<This>
    This doA()

class Foo extends Bar<Foo>

Foo has a method "Foo doA()", inherited from Bar<Foo>
```

This is the most popular use case for the `A extends B<A>` pattern. It is an isolated  workaround/trick. It adds no semantics in relationship between A and B.

It is also a popular practice to constraint `This` like

```
class Bar<This extends Bar<This>>
```

It is ugly and useless, I strongly recommend against it. Simply use "This" as a convention to indicate what it is for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I didn't have nerves to write. Well done.

Comment: I do not think `class Bar<This> { This doA() { return this; } }` can compile.  Otherwise, you can do `new Bar<String>().doA()`, which returns this a `Bar<String>` as a `String`.  So you need the `Bar<This extends Bar<This>>`

Comment: @TroyDaniels - yes, that will add some constraint to `This`; unfortunately the constraint isn't strong enough. you can have `Zoo extends Bar<Foo>` where `Foo extends Bar<Foo>`. `Zoo` is clearly a mistake! In practice though, I don't think it matters, it's rare to make such mistake; that's also why I'd drop the constraint all together (in most use cases). Programmers intuitively will not write `Bar<String>`, because `String` is not a `Bar`.

Comment: @ZhongYu it's true that the constraint is not strong enough, but it still ensures that it's much harder to create a runtime exception by chance than without the constraint. I have mixed feelings about both versions

Answer (score 8):

Try this in class A:

```
public <T extends A> T setX() {
    return (T) this;
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
B b = new B().setX();
```

Comment: This is really great ttrick! I could have never imagined tha wiould pass (you can assign any incorrect subtype as in B = a.setX(), C = a.setX()

Comment: This yields an unchecked cast warning, though.

Comment: To avoid the unchecked cast warning (because in this case, we can know for sure the cast is correct, even though the compiler doesn’t know), use: `

    public <T extends A> T setX() {  
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final T that = (T) this;  
        return that;  
    }
`

Answer (score 4):

If you really don't like the cast you can let `B` override the method

```
@Override
public B setX() {
    super.setX();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I do now. I intend to make an API as user-friendly as possible, so a little work on my side is OK. But still... :)

Comment: Of course, if it helps make your API better it sure is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the method `setX()` returns object of class `A` and you are trying to write it to an object of class `B`. It can be done vice-versa without casting (`A a = new B();`), but this way you have to cast it because the statement `B b = new B().setX();` is similar to `B b = new A();` which can't be done.

Comment: Please guys. I know basics of Java. I am looking for a way to overcome this unwanted effect to shorten the code. It's obvious that the type is B. I can tell it, you can tell it, so the compiler should be able to tell it too. The question is: Is Java capable of that?

Comment: @OndraŽižka if you know basic Java *as you said* then you **must know** that **this can't be done**.

Comment: @OndraŽižka then well, you have a comment and an answer (that basically says the same as my comment) that **you can't do this**. Note that generics could not be part of basics, but it is based on the basics. Looks like you really didn't understand the basics to begin with...

Comment: @OndraŽižka The fact that generics aren't basic is an excuse. There's no reason for this feature to even be under the scope of generics - it could've been there in Java 1.0 with some sort of `thisclass` keyword. It simply isn't there in Java as a whole. It's kind of like asking why the cookies aren't in the one drawer you can't reach, when the reason why the cookies aren't in the whole house is because nobody ever bought cookies.

Comment: @Hovercraft. That depends on what exactly you mean. Obviously it can't be done with the runtime type, but I'm not so sure that it can't be done statically. Generics are insanely complicated.

Comment: @Antimony it can be done statically. Look at BheshGurung answer (of course, you will get lot of cumbersome code).