# Why Does the following code with Cyclic Generics not compile?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Following is my code

```
class A<B2 extends B, A2 extends A<B2, A2>> {
    C<B2, A2> c;

    void test() {
        c.acceptParameterOfTypeA(this);
    }

}

class B {

}

class C<B2 extends B, A2 extends A<B2, A2>> {
    void acceptParameterOfTypeA(A2 a) {

    }
}
```

The error occurs at `c.acceptParameterOfTypeA(this);`.

The error is

> The method acceptParameterOfTypeA(A2) in the type C is not
>   applicable for the arguments (A)

From what I see, the method `acceptParameterOfTypeA` expects a parameter of type A, and `this` at the line giving the error is of type A.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this problem?

If its important, I'm using Java8

Comment: `class B<A2 extends A> {` there, the `A` parameter looks raw to me.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, I think I got the wrong example maybe. WIll try to see if I can improve. Thanks!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks, I updated the question with the actual scenario I'm facing.

Comment: You can simplify the problem to: `class A<A2 extends A<A2>> { void test() { A2 x = this; } }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will again rename your classes, so that everything is more readable. So, let's have:

```
public class First<T extends Second, U extends First<T, U>> {
    Third<T, U> c;

    void test() {
        c.acceptParameterOfTypeA(this);
    }

}

class Second {

}

public class Third<X extends Second, Y extends First<X, Y>> {
    void acceptParameterOfTypeA(Y a) {

    }
}
```

From the definition of the `c` member (`Third<T, U>`), we can conclude that `c` will expose a method with this signature:

```
void acceptParameterOfTypeA(U a) { .. }
```

What is `U`? `U` is a sub-type of `First<T, U>`.

But if `U` can be substituted with `First` after type-erasure, this will mean that `First extends First<T, First>`, which is not true, because `U` stands for sub-type of `First`, which is parameterized with some concrete sub-types of `Second` and `First`.

In order to get to `U`, you can apply the so-called **`Get This`** approach.

First, since you need `U`, which is a sub-type of `First`, but can't get it from `First`, you can introduce an `abstract` method that returns it:

```
abstract class First<T extends Second, U extends First<T, U>> {
    Third<T, U> c;

    void test() {
        c.acceptParameterOfTypeA(getU());
    }

    abstract U getU();

}
```

Then, implement a sample sub-class of `First`, called `Fourth`, which extends `First` with some concrete types for `T` and `U`, for example:

```
class Fourth extends First<Second, Fourth> {
    Fourth getU() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

In the `getU()` method, just do `return this;` as this will return the correct substitute for `U` in the super-class.

More info:

- [What is the "getThis" trick?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206)
- [Strategy Pattern with Generics](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/newsletter.do?issue=123)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `c.acceptParameterOfTypeA()` accepts `A2`. `this` has type `A<B2, A2>`, which is not known to extend `A2`. It's only known that `A2` extends `A<B2, A2>`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `kocko`'s answer, the original question had the same solution:

```
public class Main {
    abstract class A<A2 extends A<A2, B2>, B2 extends B<A2, B2>> {
        B2 b;

        void test() {
            b.testMethod(getThis()); //getThis() instead of this;
        }

        abstract A2 getThis();
    }

    class B<A2 extends A<A2, B2>, B2 extends B<A2, B2>> {
        void testMethod(A2 a) {

        }
    }

    public void execute() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify  it by removing the `B` part which doesn't contribute to the problem -

```
class A<T extends A<T>>
{
    void test(C<T> c)
    {
        c.acceptParameterOfTypeA(this);  // ERROR
    }
}

class C<T extends A<T>>
{
    void acceptParameterOfTypeA(T a) {}
}
```

`this` type is `A<T>`; and the question is whether `A<T> <: T`, which is false.

What we really want here is "self type", so that `this` type is `T`. We don't have that in Java.

Usually we use `T extends A<T>` for "self type"; but it is flawed and inadequate in some use cases.

One remedy for that is `T getThis()`, as kocko mentioned.

You could simply do a brute cast `(T)this`, which is obviously correct by the intention of `T`.

---

My preferred approach is to simply omit the bound of `T`, and rename it to `This` to indicate the purpose of the type variable. Casting `(This)this` looks obviously correct. See my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656295/2158288). That approach usually works; but it doesn't work here, since `C` would need `This` to have the bound `A<This>`. The deeper problem is `A` and `C` depends on each other, which might be redesigned.