# Using Generics in Base Presenter with Mosby and Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, mosby

I'm trying to set up a Base Presenter using Mosby's MvpBasePresenter in Dagger 2 I have the following base component:

```
public interface BaseViewComponent<V extends BaseView, P extends BasePresenter> {
    void injectView(V object);

    void injectPresenter(P object);

    P getPresenter();
}
```

with the following BasePresenter

```
public class BasePresenter <V extends BaseView> extends MvpBasePresenter {
    @Inject public BasePresenter () {

    }
}
```

and the following BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<P extends BasePresenter, C extends BaseViewComponent> extends MvpActivity implements BaseView<P> {

@Inject C mComponent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getViewContentId() != 0) {
        setContentView(getViewContentId());
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

}

@Override
public P createPresenter() {
    return mComponent.getPresenter();
}
}
```

For some reason the create presenter is showing as returning type BasePresenter and not type P even though the component getPresenter returns P. anyone have any insight? is this even a good idea to do?

Comment: I'm not sure generics in this way get supported, you could try providing it genericly in modules like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224927/injecting-generics-in-dagger

Comment: Can you please show `BaseView`?

Comment: BaseView is basically just empty at the moment such that BaseView<P>

Comment: Does `interface BaseView extends MvpView`?

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is the following, similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706582/why-does-the-following-code-with-cyclic-generics-not-compile)

```
public interface BaseViewComponent<V extends BaseView<V, P>, P extends BasePresenter<V, P>> {
    void injectView(V object);

    void injectPresenter(P object);

    P getPresenter();
}

public class BasePresenter<V extends BaseView<V, P>, P extends BasePresenter<V, P>> extends MvpBasePresenter {
    @Inject public BasePresenter () {

    }
}

public abstract class BaseActivity<V extends BaseView<V, P>, P extends BasePresenter<V, P>, C extends BaseViewComponent<V, P>> 
    extends MvpActivity 
    implements BaseView<V, P> {

@Inject C mComponent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getViewContentId() != 0) {
        setContentView(getViewContentId());
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

}

@Override
public P createPresenter() {
    return mComponent.getPresenter();
}
}
```

Comment: it would seem then i get something along the lines of 

Error:com.hannesdorfmann.mosby.mvp.MvpBasePresenter has type parameters, cannot members inject the raw type. via: injectPresenter(p object) 

looks like i can't do it

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure this should be possible. Although I do think you will need to use modules instead of @Inject constructor.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm not sure i follow