# what the usefulness about Java generics involving inheritance and generics extends self

Tags: java, generics

I find the generics whose generics params extends itself([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171797/java-generics-involving-inheritance-and-this/33172204#comment54175706_33172204)). I don't understand that well.I suspect that it is wrong at the beginning, but no one put forward. I have some questions about this:

1. How to use the Variant generics, can you give me a example?
2. What the benefit or effect of this generics style.

here is the generics style code which is picked from ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171797/java-generics-involving-inheritance-and-this/33172204#comment54175706_33172204)).

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>> {

}

class Variant<T extends Variant<T>> extends Base<T> {

}
```

Thanks！

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/211143/4125191) about the recursive definition of `Enum`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17099185/2158288

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about [F-bounded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification). I've found them very useful in situations where two hierarchies are directly correlated. The most clear case that comes to mind is the builder pattern, targeted to a hierarchy of classes. In this case, it could be of use to have a hierarchy of builders as well.

An example might shed some light. Consider the following (very stereotyped) hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Human {

    protected String name;

    protected int age;
}

public class Woman extends Human {

    protected String loveMovie;
}

public class Man extends Human {

    protected String soccerTeam;
}
```

Now, we want to create builders for `Man` and `Woman`. We could implement a builder for each one, duplicating the methods to set `name` and `age` attributes. However, as `Man` and `Woman` inherit from `Human`, we could have an abstract `HumanBuilder`, and make our `WomanBuilder` and `ManBuilder` inherit from it. This is where F-bounded types come in handy.

The `Human` class, along with its `HumanBuilder`, would be as follows:

```
public abstract class Human {

    protected String name;

    protected int age;

    public static abstract class HumanBuilder<H extends Human, 
                                              T extends HumanBuilder<H, T>> {
        protected String name;

        protected int age;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return (T) this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T age(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return (T) this;
        }

        protected void fill(H human) {
            human.name = this.name;
            human.age = this.age;
        }

        protected abstract H create();

        public final H build() {
            H human = this.create();
            this.fill(human);
            return human;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be the `Woman` class, along with its `WomanBuilder`:

```
public class Woman extends Human {

    protected String loveMovie;

    public static class WomanBuilder extends HumanBuilder<Woman, WomanBuilder> {

        protected String loveMovie;

        public WomanBuilder loveMovie(String loveMovie) {
            this.loveMovie = loveMovie;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected void fill(Woman woman) {
            super.fill(woman);
            woman.loveMovie = this.loveMovie;
        }

        @Override
        protected Woman create() {
            return new Woman();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the `Man` class, along with its `ManBuilder`:

```
public class Man extends Human {

    protected String soccerTeam;

    public static class ManBuilder extends HumanBuilder<Man, ManBuilder> {

        protected String soccerTeam;

        public ManBuilder soccerTeam(String soccerTeam) {
            this.soccerTeam = soccerTeam;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected void fill(Man man) {
            super.fill(man);
            man.soccerTeam = this.soccerTeam;
        }

        @Override
        protected Man create() {
            return new Man();
        }
    }
}
```

This approach saves quite a lot of lines of code, especially in a real-world use case.

As expected, using the builders does not require any casting:

```
Man man = new Man.ManBuilder()
    .name("Joe")
    .age(29)
    .soccerTeam("Los Angeles Galaxy")
    .build();

Woman woman = new Woman.WomanBuilder()
    .name("Jane")
    .age(25)
    .loveMovie("Meet Joe Black")
    .build();
```

Comment: The builders should receive a `Man` and a `Woman` instance in their constructor :-D

Comment: @Marco13 That would be the `BabyBuilder` :P

Answer (score 1):

From the code you linked, it looks like the Base and Variant classes hold methods that return references to an object of their own class, I'm guessing similar to a Singleton.

```
abstract class Base {
    protected abstract Base getNewInstance();
}
```

Now if you wanted to return an instance of a subclass of Base, you'd be out of luck. That's where generics come in.

```
class Variant<T extends Variant<T>> extends Base<T> {
    protected Base<T> getNewInstance() { 
        return new Variant(); 
    }
}
```

In regards to usefulness, I personally don't really see any. It's unnecessarily complicated and could probably be refactored to something much more readable.

Comment: Your second example would be relevant if `getNewInstance` declared `T` as its return type.  As it is now, you are gaining no benefit from `T extends Variant<T>` as you are declaring `Base<T>` as your return type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example. You need to write an algorithm which takes an `Iterable` of any type `T` and returns minimum of those objects. To define relative order over type `T` you need either pass `Comparator` over `T` or, as alternative, require type `T` extends `Comparable<T>`. This is convenient alternative, because many built-in types like `String`, `Integer`, etc. already does.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(Iterable<T> args) {
    T m = null;
    for (T arg : args)
        m = (m == null || arg.compareTo(m) < 0) ? arg : m;
    return m;
}
```

This is not exactly form of extending your are talking about, but closely related. Generic extending itself might be useful in tree structures, for example.