# Alternatives to CRTP in Java

Tags: java, generics, crtp

The [*CRTP*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern allows to emulate the so called [*self types*](http://web.archive.org/web/20130721224442/http:/passion.forco.de/content/emulating-self-types-using-java-generics-simplify-fluent-api-implementation) in *Java*, e. g.:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo<SELF extends AbstractFoo<SELF>> implements Comparable<SELF> {
    @Override
    public final int compareTo(final SELF o) {
        // ...
    }
}

final class C1 extends AbstractFoo<C1> {
    // ...
}

final class C2 extends AbstractFoo<C2> {
    // ...
}
```

With the above code (the `Comparable` interface has been chosen just for clarity; of course there're other use cases), I can easily compare two instances of `C1`:

```
new C1().compareTo(new C1());
```

but not `AbstractFoo` descendants whose concrete types are different:

```
new C1().compareTo(new C2()); // compilation error
```

It's easy to abuse the pattern, however:

```
final class C3 extends AbstractFoo<C1> {
    // ...
}

// ...

new C3().compareTo(new C1()); // compiles cleanly
```

Also, the type checks are purely compile-time ones, i. e. one can easily mix `C1` and `C2` instances in a single `TreeSet` and have them compared with each other.

What alternative to *CRTP* in *Java* emulates *self types* without the potential for abuse as shown above?

**P. S.** I observe the pattern is not widely used in the standard library -- only `EnumSet` and its descendants implement it.

Comment: What measurement determines whether an alternative is _better_ than CRTP? The question sounds subjective.

Comment: @jaco0646 Well, I understand the question may sound opinion-based, but I would appreciate _any_ response descibing possible alternatives. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If _any_ alternative is acceptable, the question becomes too broad: there is no basis for comparing potential answers. FYI, I think the question is interesting, so I'm trying to nudge it towards being less open-ended. Perhaps, "_What alternative to CRTP in Java emulates self types without the potential for abuse as shown above?_"

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks, edited as you're suggesting.

Comment: @Bass [this may be?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33188544/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene Thank you. Formally, this may qualify as the correct answer to my question. Still, it requires way much more _library_ code to be written if you're an author of the API, duplicating identical implementations. Take a look at the [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) library -- its code would have grown twice its current size =)

Comment: @Eugene Also, your approach works for *method return types*, but doesn’t for *method parameters*.

Comment: @Bass I barely read that, it was just a suggestion..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think what you showed is "abuse". All the code that uses `AbstractFoo` and `C3` are still perfectly type-safe, as long as they don't do any unsafe casts. The bounds of `SELF` in `AbstractFoo` means that the code can rely on the fact that `SELF` is a subtype of `AbstractFoo<SELF>`, but the code cannot rely on the fact that `AbstractFoo<SELF>` is a subtype of `SELF`. So for example, if `AbstractFoo` had a method that returned `SELF`, and it was implemented by returning `this` (as should be possible if it were really a "self-type"), it would not compile:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo<SELF extends AbstractFoo<SELF>> {
    public SELF someMethod() {
        return this; // would not compile
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't let you compile this because it is unsafe. For example, running this method on `C3` would return `this` (which is really a `C3` instance) as type `C1`, which would cause a class cast exception in the calling code. If you tried to sneak past the compiler by using a cast, like `return (SELF)this;`, then you get an unchecked cast warning which means you take responsibility for it being unsafe.

And if your `AbstractFoo` is really used in a way that only relied on the fact that `SELF extends AbstractFoo<SELF>` (as the bound says), and does not rely on the fact that `AbstractFoo<SELF> extends SELF`, then why do you care about the "abuse" of `C3`? You can still write your classes `C1 extends AbstractFoo<C1>` and `C2 extends AbstractFoo<C2>` fine. And if someone else decides to write a class `C3 extends AbstractFoo<C1>`, then as long as they write it in a way without using unsafe casts, the compiler guarantees that it is still type-safe. Perhaps such a class might not be able to do anything useful; I don't know. But it is still safe; so why is that a problem?

The reason why a recursive bound like `<SELF extends AbstractFoo<SELF>>` is not used much is that, in most cases, it is not any more useful than `<SELF>`. For example, the `Comparable` interface's type parameter doesn't have a bound. If someone decides to write a class `Foo extends Comparable<Bar>`, they can do so, and it is type-safe, though not very useful, because in most classes and methods that use `Comparable`, they have a type variable `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, which requires that `T` is comparable to itself, so the `Foo` class would not be usable as a type argument in any of those places. But it is still fine for someone to write `Foo extends Comparable<Bar>` if they want.

The only places where a recursive bound like `<SELF extends AbstractFoo<SELF>>` is in a place which actually makes use of the fact that `SELF` extends `AbstractFoo<SELF>`, which is quite rare. One place is in something like the builder pattern, which has methods that return the object itself, which can be chained. So if you have methods like

```
abstract class AbstractFoo<SELF extends AbstractFoo<SELF>> {
    public SELF foo() { }
    public SELF bar() { }
    public SELF baz() { }
}
```

and you had a general value of `AbstractFoo<?> x`, you can do things like `x.foo().bar().baz()` which you could not do if it were declared as `abstract class AbstractFoo<SELF>`.

There isn't a way in Java Generics to make a type parameter that must be the same type as the current implementing class. If, hypothetically, there were such a mechanism, that could cause tricky problems with inheritance:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo<SELF must be own type> {
    public abstract int compareTo(SELF o);
}

class C1 extends AbstractFoo<C1> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(C1 o) {
        // ...
    }
}

class SubC1 extends C1 {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(/* should it take C1 or SubC1? */) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here, `SubC1` implicitly inherits `AbstractFoo<C1>`, but that breaks the contract that `SELF` must be the type of the implementing class. If `SubC1.compareTo()` must take a `C1` argument, then it is no longer true that the type of the thing received is the same type as the current object itself. If `SubC1.compareTo()` can take a `SubC1` argument, then it is no longer overrides `C1.compareTo()`, as it no longer takes as wide a set of the arguments as the method in the superclass takes.